# How to create a boolean tensor whose values are drawn from a Bernoulli distribution?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor, bernoulli-probability

I would like to implement the following function:

```
def bernoulli_tensor(shape, probability) -> tf.Tensor:
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible implementation:

```
from typing import List

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp



def bernoulli(shape: List[int], truth_probability: float = 0.5) -> tf.Tensor:
    distribution = tfp.distributions.Bernoulli(probs=truth_probability)
    return tf.cast(distribution.sample(shape), dtype=tf.dtypes.bool)
```